# disable @Nonnull annotation on "implement methods"

Tags: intellij-idea, non-nullable

IntelliJ is adding `@Nonnull` annotations on code generated via the `implement methods` feature. How to prevent IntelliJ from annotating signatures with that annotation?

IntelliJ 2019.1

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the interface signature annotated with `@NotNull`? Why do you want the implementation to omit the annotation?

Comment: @CrazyCoder - you are right! the method signatures on the interface are annotated with `@Nonnull`. I did not notice that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA copies the annotations from the interface declaration, there is no way to disable this behavior.